# Running Heroku background tasks with only 1 web dyno and 0 worker dynos

Tags: python, heroku, redis

I have a Python Flask app on Heroku that serves web pages but also allows certain tasks to be launched which I believe would be best structured as background tasks.  As such, I've followed the [Heroku `rq` tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) to set up background tasks.  My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: python app.py
worker: python worker.py
```

However, my processes are currently scaled `web=1 worker=0`.  Given that this background process won't be run very often, it doesn't seem sensible to me to provision an entire dyno for it and then pay the $34/month for something that small.

**Question:**

- If I leave the `worker` process declared in my Procfile but keep the scaling at `web=1 worker=0`, will my queued processes eventually be run on my available web dyno?  Or will the queued processes never run?
- If the queued processes will never run, is there another way to do this short of, for example, using `twisted` in my web app to run the tasks asynchronously?

**Additional Information**

`worker.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

The logic in the main app that enqueues a process looks like this:

```
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn
q = Queue(connection=conn)

q.enqueue(myfunction, myargument)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how heroku works, but couldn't you just spawn a worker thread? You could use a Queue to push a job to it...

Comment: @korylprince Yes, I could do that--that's what I meant by writing it into the code asynchronously.  I'd prefer to do it with the queue if possible, though.

Answer (score 13):

Modify `Procfile` to look like this:

```
web: bin/web
```

Now create the `bin` directory, and create the file `bin/web` to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python app.py &
python worker.py
```

Make sure you give this file the executable permission:

```
$ chmod +x bin/web
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by this, but it would be more helpful both to me and the community if you would explain your answer further.

Comment: Basically what he's doing is first he run application in the background and then worker in the foreground.

Comment: > "Is this a good practice?"
Good practive is to have multiple dynos - that's heroku for. But for one dyno-purposes - why not.

Comment: Answer is coming from python guy at Heroku. Answer is working fine but more explanation would be good.

Comment: I have been searching for hours, and I think I understand this answer, but I am not able to find a suitable solution for my needs. How would I achieve having a web site and background process on the same dyno using ruby on rails?

Comment: This is all fine and dandy until heroku shuts your web app down , because no one is acessing it. which ends up stopping your worker

Comment: @NunoFurtado We're already talking about "abusing" the free service a little bit. Note that they don't "shut down" dynos  you actually pay for.

Comment: @NunoFurtado you could write a bash script to hit the web app with cURL, at whatever interval you needed, and run it with cron. Or you could just pay the ~$0.0 for a micro instance on AWS

Comment: What happens when the site gets shut down, and the worker stops? Also, I was unable to use this fix because of the file name 'bin/web' -- heroku couldn't find it bash: bin/web: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently running both my web and backend scheduler in Heroku using only 1 dyno.

Idea is to provide one main python script for Heroku to start in 1 dyno. This script is used to start both the web server process(es) and the customer scheduler process(es). 
You can then define your jobs and add them to the custom scheduler.

[APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is used in my case.

This is what I did:

in Procfile:

```
 web: python run_app.py    #the main startup script
```

in the run_app.py:

```
# All the required imports
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from run_housekeeping import run_housekeeping
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import os

def run_web_script():
    # start the gunicorn server with custom configuration
    # You can also using app.run() if you want to use the flask built-in server -- be careful about the port
    os.system('gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py web.jobboard:app --debug')  

def start_scheduler():

     # define a background schedule 
     # Attention: you cannot use a blocking scheduler here as that will block the script from proceeding.
     scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

     # define your job trigger
     hourse_keeping_trigger = CronTrigger(hour='12', minute='30')

     # add your job
     scheduler.add_job(func=run_housekeeping, trigger=hourse_keeping_trigger)

     # start the scheduler
     scheduler.start()


def run():
    start_scheduler()
    run_web_script()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I am also using 4 Worker processes for serving the web from Gunicorn -- which runs perfectly fine.

In gunicorn.conf.py:

```
loglevel = 'info'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
workers = 4
```

You may want to checkout this project as an example: [Zjobs@Github](https://github.com/mengfeng/zjobs)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a process manager such as [god](http://godrb.com/) or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

With god, you can set up your configuration like so

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "app"
  w.start = "python app.py"
  w.keepalive
end

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "worker"
  w.start = "python worker.py"
  w.keepalive
end
```

Then you put this in your Procfile

```
god -c path/to/config.god -D
```

By default, it automatically restarts the process if it crashes, and you can configure it to restart the app if memory usage gets too high. Check out the documentation.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

To start and run a process in background:

Procfile:

```
run: python my_app.py
```

And later, execute:

```
heroku ps:scale run=1
```

Answer (score -2):

You should take a look at [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) it will allow you to run a specific task on a scheduled interval such as every 10 minutes. If you already have your worker setup you could add:

```
heroku run worker
```

Comment: I know I could do this, but using Heroku scheduler isn't really the same as having a background queue.  That's a cron job, and the 10-minute wait can be far too long for tasks that I just want to push to the background in order not to delay the page loading.

Comment: Another option would be to us the heroku API and run a process in a detached mode. By needing an entire queue you'll either need a running process or to have it running in the same Dyno. If you use the heroku API and issue a heroku run command in detached mode it would act almost as if it were a queue.

Comment: Agreed, I was envisioning it running in the same dyno.